# Trying to understand ES6 Promises: executing three setIntervals sequentially

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

In order to understand how ES6 Promises I tried to solve this problem statement:

There are three divs: `div.red`, `div.green`, and `div.blue`. They have to appear one after another, each by a **`setInterval` iterative opacity increment** (async task).

So the goal is to sequentially execute 3 async tasks.

I have written the following code, This goes into the reject part and gives a ***TypeError**: undefined is not a function {stack: (...), message: "undefined is not a function"}*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    div{ width:100px; height:100px; opacity:0; }
    .red{ background:red; }
    .green{ background:green; }
    .blue{ background:blue; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function appear(div){
        console.log("appear");
        console.log(div);
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            console.log("promise");
            console.log(div.attr("class"));
            var i = 0;
            var loop = setInterval(function(){
                if (i == 1){
                    clearInterval(loop);
                    console.log("animation end");
                    resolve(true);
                }
                div.css({"opacity": i});
                i+=0.1;
            },100);
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var divList = []
        $("div").each(function(){
            divList.push($(this));
        });
        console.log("start");
        (function(){
            return divList.reduce(function(current, next) {
                return appear(current).then(function() {
                    return appear(next);
                }, function(err) { console.log(err); }).then(function() {
                    console.log("div animation complete!")
                }, function(err) { console.log(err); });
            }, Promise.resolve()).then(function(result) {
                console.log("all div animation done!");
            }, function(err) { console.log(err); });
        })();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well which line gives the error?

Comment: @Mathletics http://prntscr.com/55dao9
u can see the console logs and errors, line 57 is generating the error.

Comment: You should indicate which is line 57 in your question, links rot and users shouldnt have to go to an external site to get this information.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle for this? It's likely something simple but it's not obvious to me without being able to run it.

Comment: @Mathletics http://jsbin.com/tazefo/6/edit?html,css,js,console,output
but the console errors are error objects so u can see its properties in jsbin console.
Is best to copy the whole code block in the question into a html file and see the console errors.
use chrome 32+

Comment: JSBin is the worst (/opinion) and you forgot to include the code that runs your example. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m8wkhsqy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, you call `appear(current)`. However, `current` is the promise that represents the current (latest) step of your chain, not the div. It will initially get passed the `Promise.resolve()`, which is not a jQuery object and does not have an `.attr()` method.

Instead, use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("start");
    $("div").toArray().reduce(function(currentPromise, nextDiv) {
        return currentPromise.then(function() {
            return appear($(nextDiv));
        });
    }, Promise.resolve()).then(function() {
         console.log("all div animation complete!")
    }, function(err) {
         console.log(err);
    });
});
```